# Will JAX WS Web Service generation always create XSD file

Tags: web-services, xsd, websphere, jax-ws, rad

I am using RAD 7.5 to generate WSDL from java service class using JAX-WS. My Server is WAS 7.0. I am not able to see any option in RAD to exclude the XSD generation and include the request & response type object details in WSDL itself.

Is this possible to create a WSDL file which will also hold the request & response object detail using JAX-WS? I dont want to have XSD file.

I am new to Web Service, please let me know if I am thinking something rubbish :)

Comment: Question makes sense. I don't know the answer :-)